# How to elegantly find element?

Tags: javascript

Given the following array named clusters, what's an elegant way to get the object with smallest value for distance?  Sorry, bit of a JS newbie here.

```
var clusters = []

clusters.push({
  description:"Frankfurt",
  distance:18492.53622406789,
  id:"ahcg4_rnrCJ2kQJ-BkP3v4JS",
  url:"https://frankfurt.example.com",
  name:"eu-central-1"
})

clusters.push({
    description:"Oregon",
    distance:11471.556955008904,
    id:"6RazgBDmGW0GBAyokoLFNyYp",
    manager_url:"https://oregon.example.com",
    name:"us-west-2"
})
```

There has to be a more elegant way than the conventional for loop by using reduce or similar?  e.g. how would I write this as a one liner with reduce ?  or something equally simple

Comment: `There has to be a more elegant way` - why? can you even conceive such a "method"?

Comment: When you say "for loop with reduce", do you mean `Array.prototype.reduce`? I can't imagine there's a much simpler way that `clusters.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.distance < b.distance ? a : b; })`

Comment: @AaronBallard - that's what I was trying to write instead of a for loop but didn't understand how reduce works.  I think I got it now, thanks!

Comment: Keep them sorted when inserting them, then just access the first - would that be elegant enough?

Comment: @Bergi - nope, that list comes from a query and they can appear in any order.

Comment: @Matt You should have told us that… But really then the most elegant way would be to provide a `?sortBy=distance&limit=1` option in that query API.

Comment: Sorry @Bergi - it can take a lot of thought to remove ambiguity and get thoughts written down.  I hope the question is now clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer since you said it helped. Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you can iterate through the array, comparing the current and next items, and returning whichever one has the smaller distance, finally returning the object with the smallest distance in the entire array.

```
var smallest = clusters.reduce(
  function(current, next) {
    return current.distance < next.distance ? current : next;
  }
);
```

You can also be a little more succinct with ES6.

```
let smallest = clusters.reduce((current, next) =>
  current.distance < next.distance ? current : next;
);
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the minimum, you will by definition have to visit each element. To visit each element involves some kind of iteration, whether that be a for loop, or a `reduce`, as in:

```
clusters.reduce(
  (smallest, cluster) => cluster.distance < smallest.distance ? cluster : smallest);
```

You could also consider sorting the array by distance and taking the first (smallest) element of the result:

```
clusters.slice().sort((x, y) => x.distance - y.distance)[0]
```

However, this is doing more work than you really need to.

Another alternative, if you have hundreds of thousands of these objects, would be to cache the element with the smallest value and update it whenever an element is added to the array.

```
let clusterWithSmallestDistance;

function addCluster(cluster) {
  if (!clusterWithSmallestDistance || 
    cluster.distance < clusterWithSmallestDistance.distance)
      clusterWithSmallestDistance = cluster;
  clusters.push(cluster);
}
```

Comment: Only 2 right now, could grow up to 20 or 30 in the future.  Not an issue really.  Thanks

Comment: Might want to `.slice` before that sort. Not sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give my input too. I'm drawn towards this kind of questions..

```
let _min = (a,b) => Math.min(a,b); 
//Making it our own function the because `reduce` callback has other parameters
//Also - aesthetics 
let smallestDistance = cluster.map(c => c.distance)
                              .reduce(_min);
```

Or

```
let distances = cluster.map(c => c.distance);
let smallestDistance = Math.min(...distances);
```

But I thought you might want to keep the reference to the object with the smallest distance, in this case torazaburo has already given the answer, here's my own touch to the solution

```
let _getSmaller = prop => (a,b) => a[prop] < b[prop] ? a : b;
let nearest = cluster.reduce(_getSmaller('distance'));
```

One case that the above code does not cover is when 2 objects has the same distance. The code assumes you'll take the latter value down the array. To reverse that you could use `reduceRight` or add another conditional. Thanks for the question!